# Git: how do I delete remotely available files and keep only locally changed files

Tags: git

Some time ago, I cloned a remote repository of someone else onto my local machine.

Over the term of the project I changed some files locally and partly had them in my local git version control.

Now, since the project has ended and the files take a lot of space on my machine, I want to delete all those files, which can be drawn from the remote repository once I need them again.

I want to keep, however, all the files (and versions) I changed locally.

Is there an (elegant) way to do this with git without finding all the finds manually by going through my entire git history? So far, I couldn't find a post, which could give me an answer on this question.

Comment: This is not a supported use case, but it *can* be achieved to a degree using shallow clones (which have some very annoying restrictions).

Comment: Have you looked at sparse checkout?

Comment: _Sparse checkouts_ seem to be the right direction. Thanks for the hint!
However, I still don't get how I can retrieve a list of the files I want to respect. What I found so far is that I need to tell git manually which files I want to consider in a sparse checkout, right? Is therer a command, which lets me retrieve those files that are not "touched" locally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find all the commits whose author name is you, in the reverse order:

```
git log --pretty=%H --author=Markus --reverse
```

List the modified/added/renamed files of a commit `$commit`, excluding deleted files:

```
git log -1 ${commit} --diff-filter=d --name-only --pretty=
```

Archive these files of `$commit`:

```
git archive -o ${commit}.zip ${commit} ${files}
```

Combine them:

```
n=0
for commit in $(git log --pretty=%H --author=Markus --reverse);do
   n=$((n+1))
   git archive -o ${n}-${commit}.zip  ${commit} $(git log -1 ${commit} --diff-filter=d --name-only --pretty=)
done
```

The output is `1-xxx.zip`, `2-xxx.zip`, etc. `1-xxx.zip` is the oldest commit and its changed files.

This method takes almost the smallest space.

Update:

Unfortunately, this method keeps only the archived files. The commits and related git metadata are gone if you remove the local repository without backing them up. To reuse the metadata at the lowest cost of space, I recommend `git bundle`. For example, you can bundle the branches `foo` and `bar`:

```
git bundle create my.bundle foo bar
```

If you clone the repository again and want to reuse the commits you have made, you can run in the repository:

```
git fetch <path_to_my.bundle> foo:backup_foo
git fetch <path_to_my.bundle> bar:backup_bar
```

The commits are now available from the branches `backup_foo` and `backup_bar` in the newly-cloned repository. You can then manipulate the branches and commits. `my.bundle` works as a read-only remote repository. You can also create a remote for `path_to_my.bundle`, for example with `git remote add backup <path_to_my.bundle>` so that you can run `git fetch backup foo:backup_foo`.

With `my.bundle`, you can remove the previously-cloned repository to save space.

I tried to bundle a shallow branch, and then a range of commits, but both bundles threw errors when I tried to clone or fetch them. So I thinks this way it costs the lowest space. But if you can push them to a remote repository, like one on Github or Gitlab, or upload the repository or the bundle to a service like Dropbox, you can even save the local space.

Comment: Wow, this looks great! Thanks a lot!
One question, though: If, at a certain point in time, I want to continue with my project as I left it... would this be possible? Say, I want to clone the remote repo again and populate the local version with my archives, which I previously created following your method.?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update! That seems to be a really nice solution :-)